# How to make "tar --exclude" behave consistently across *nix environments?

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I am writing a bash script to make a deployment tarball and the script must work across OSX and Linux.

I have a directory structure as shown below and in a bash script I need to tar the contents excluding `./foo` but including `./baz/foo`

```
$ find .
.
./bar
./baz
./baz/foo
./foo
```

Simple! Normally I would do this by passing `--exclude='./foo'` to the tar command but I am finding the behaviour of `--exclude=pattern` is different across OSX and CentOS.

My question is, how best to overcome this? How can I make both environments behave the same or at least detect the changes needed?

Or, can anyone confirm this behaviour for them (OSX 10.11) so that I know I haven't got some weird environment?

CentOS works as expected:

```
$ tar zcfv ../test.tar.gz --exclude='./foo' .
./
./bar/
./baz/
./baz/foo/
```

OSX behaves differently:

```
$ tar zcfv ../test.tar.gz --exclude='./foo' .
a .
a ./bar
a ./baz
```

After hours of reading documentation I have found nothing to explain this different behaviour, but through trial and error I have found that using a caret to denote the start of the pattern works on OSX.

A fix for OSX (using caret):

```
$ tar zcfv ../test.tar.gz --exclude='^./foo' .
a .
a ./bar
a ./baz
a ./baz/foo
```

But doesn't work on CentOS:

```
$ tar zcfv ../test.tar.gz --exclude='^./foo' .
./
./bar/
./foo/
./baz/
./baz/foo/
```

And finally, I notice that OSX ships with bsdtar instead of GNU tar, so is this the root of the problem?

OSX:

```
$ tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
```

CentOS:

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.23
```

Comment: One option is to use brew to install GNU tar on OSX. The only other way I can think of that may work is to do some kind of check on the version of tar installed (i.e. write something in your script to check if the user is using GNU tar, or bsdtar - then use that in some conditions to decide how to run tar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tar --exclude doesn't exclude. Why? on Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/tar-exclude-doesnt-exclude-why)

Comment: @davidcondrey - it is not the same problem as that question

Comment: @Seer - yeah I think using brew to install GNU tar is likely my only way out of this - it's far from an ideal solution though. Will probably need to check the version of tar installed and the OS within the script, and if the OS is Darwin then make sure that gnu tar is available and bail out if it isn't.

Comment: Essentially the problem is that `--exclude` is a nonstandard option which BSD tar imitates incompletely, but is based on the option from GNU tar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. It appears this is a fundamental difference between bsdtar and GNU tar in the implentation of `--exclude=pattern` and there is no way to make them behave the same.

Since I have control of the OS environment my acceptable workaround is to install GNU tar on OSX using brew (thanks @Seer). I then use the following within my script to detect whether the installed tar is GNU, and fallback to gtar if not. If gtar is not installed it will abort.

```
# OSX uses bsdtar which causes problems with --exclude=pattern
# so force use of gtar if non-GNU tar detected
tar --version | grep -q 'gnu'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Detected GNU tar - using tar"
    TAR_BIN=`command -v tar 2>&1` || { echo >&2 "I require tar but it is not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }
else
    echo "Detected non-GNU tar - using gtar"
    TAR_BIN=`command -v gtar 2>&1` || { echo >&2 "I require gtar but it is not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }
fi

# this will now work consistently as GNU tar is always used
$TAR_BIN zcfv ../test.tar.gz --exclude='./foo' .
```

Note: CentOS at least actually aliases gtar to tar, so it may be safe to just assume the use of gtar command instead, but I prefer the above method.